# TFS 2017, HTTPS Binding loses console permissions?

Tags: ssl, tfs, azure-devops

I've been trying all day to set up my instance of TFS2017 to work with HTTPS.

I've read the official setup guide, but it didn't help much.

My instance is attached to a domain and configuration has been made with an Administrators group user. The domain account is referenced as an administration console user properly.
The setup has been made with default 8080 port and domain account user can access the website as expected (hosted at http://machine-name:8080/tfs)

Now, when I change the IIS website settings binding to use HTTPS on port 443 with a valid wildchar certificate + set the hostname to be tfs.mydomain.com + ask for SSL require, I cannot have my user to authenticate anymore.
I make TFS Public Url point to https://tfs.mydomain.com/tfs.

I get prompted for the authentication box, but after many attempts, the site would just fail with 401.

The tests are made into the server environment to avoid Firewall confusions.

My instance has two network cards with 2 separate networks. First resolves to public IP, second resolves to private IP. I noticed the configuration works with the machine names, while it fails with the DNS resolution on the public IP. Could this be a reason ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you get any related error info in  **Event View** on TFS server? Did you try to use another port than 443?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform the procedures in your requirements, you must first meet some prerequisites such as required Permissions and so on. Please double check this first. Also please make sure you have set up the corresponding ports such as below prompted.

> **Important:**
>
> The default port number for SSL connections is **443**, but **you
>   must assign a unique port number for each of the following
>   sites**: Default Website, Team Foundation Server, Microsoft Team
>   Foundation Server Proxy (if your deployment uses it), and SharePoint
>   Central Administration (if your deployment uses SharePoint).
>
> You should record the SSL port number for each website that you
>   configure. You will need to specify these numbers in the
>   administration console for Team Foundation.

There is a very detail tutorial about configuring HTTPS with SSL, please refer [Setting up HTTPS with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer)

To narrow down the issue with  IP, you could disable one of your two network cards. Give a test with only using one network card each time.

Comment: I made it work. For some reason I had to configure the "Disable Loop Back Check in Windows Server" editing regedit and exclude my domain server. I'm not sure to understand why this settings was required on a 2016 server version ?

Comment: Glad to hear it. Loop Back Check in Windows Server this feature will prevent a web application access from the host server with a fully qualified domain name. Maybe there is something related to your domain.

Comment: I found a related blog [Using Friendly DNS Names in Your TFS Environment](http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx) ,including some useful info for setting up TFS Environment. You could take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, this is indeed a very nice example of advanced configuration